# Better explanation of bson spec examples?

Tags: mongodb, bson

I'm trying to understand the examples on http://bsonspec.org/#/specification in terms of how the bytes map to the BNF-ish specification, but having a difficult time. Is the text that gets bold when you mouse over either side correctly synchronized with the other side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Here's the **[Ruby implementation's mapping](http://rubydoc.info/gems/bson/1.6.1/BSON/BSON_RUBY)** if you want to verify that the constants are correct.

Comment: Thanks! I was forgetting that int32 is 4-bytes in little endian. Much easier to visually parse now :)